# Указатели c++

Tags: c#, память, указатели, c++

В C# я мог использовать свои объекты следующим образом:

```
class MyClass
{
    //тут несколько элементов и конструктор..
    //..
}
MyClass obj1;
someMethod()
{
    obj1=new MyClass(args);
    x=obj1.x;
}
```

В с++ аналогичный код не выполняется. Ошибка в строке

```
obj1=new MyClass(args);
```

пишет MyClass нельзя присвоить MyClass*.

Окей, тогда

```
MyClass *obj1;
```

Но как использовать этот указатель, я не знаю. Мне нужно некоторые поля этого объекта использовать в выражении. Например:

```
m=obj1.x+obj1.y;
```

Но в этой строке выдаёт ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так может прежде чем программировать на С++,  имеет смысл почитать о том, как это делается?

Если по теме, то (*obj1).x либо obj1->x

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.